# Xcode is creating a new branch every time I try to switch to another with Git?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a branch named development. For some reason, every time I switch to development and try to merge into another, Xcode is creating a new branch titled development1, development2, development3, etc etc. I am not sure why this is happening or how to stop it.

It left me in an unfortunate situation. We have a billion branches on the project now. Any ideas?

I'm just trying to switch and merge. This is making a mess of the project. I'm not sure how to handle it.

Comment: It's difficult to know what happened here, so I suggest this is closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was switching to the remote branches. Every time I did that, it created a new branch locally. This could be considered an Xcode bug, but I have a feeling I was simply misusing Git. I'm just picking it up.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a potential bug in Xcode. I recommend just using the command line:

1. To switch to another branch:

   `git checkout branch_name`
2. To delete a branch:

   `git checkout -d branch_name`
3. To force delete a branch (if commits on a branch are not on any other branch):

   `git checkout -D branch_name`
4. To merge with another branch

   `git checkout branch_to_change`

   `git merge branch_to_merge_into_current_branch`

Comment: agreed, the command line is definitely preferred. and this answer is definitely a possibility. but i figured out what the problem was so i cant in good conscience accept it. i will, however, +1 for usefulness